# Closing pipes in a linked system - Linux C Question

Tags: c, linux

I've been having a few issues regarding the linkage of pipes and am looking for a bit of clarification on the matter - below is a sample from the c program I am using.

I have two demos that take stdin from a file and stdout / stderr to a series of pipes. These pipes are then fed into two comparison programs, one of which takes the stdout of both demo programs and the other of which takes the stderr from both.

As it stands, I'm unsure as to which pipes to close in each child after linking them up appropriately. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
jobStruct job_handler(char* jobLine, char* testProgram, char* filename, int jobNumber, int isQuiet, int counter) {
    jobStruct jobStatus;
    jobStatus.exitStatus = 0;

    int pipeOne[2];
    int pipeTwo[2]; 
    int pipeThree[2];
    int pipeFour[2];

    pipe (pipeOne);
    pipe (pipeTwo);
    pipe (pipeThree);
    pipe (pipeFour);

    pid_t pidList[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < PROGRAM_SIZE; i ++) {
        pid_t status = fork();
        if (!status) {
            if (i == 0) {
                int inputFile = open (filename, O_RDONLY);

                args[0] = "test-program-one";

                for (int i = 0; i < argCount; i ++) {
                    args[i + 1] = jobArgs[i];
                }

                args[argCount + 1] = NULL;

                // Pipes
                dup2(inputFile, STDIN_FILENO);

                dup2(pipeOne[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
                dup2(pipeTwo[WRITE_END], STDERR_FILENO);

                // Close pipes here.

                // Exec
                execvp(args[0], args);

                // Job failed to load.
                job_failed(jobNumber);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                int inputFile = open (filename, O_RDONLY);

                args[0] = "test-program-two";

                for (int i = 0; i < argCount; i ++) {
                    args[i + 1] = jobArgs[i];
                }

                args[argCount + 1] = NULL;

                // Pipes
                dup2(inputFile, STDIN_FILENO);

                dup2(pipeThree[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
                dup2(pipeFour[WRITE_END], STDERR_FILENO);

                // Close pipes here.
                
                // Exec
                execvp(args[0], args);

                // Job failed to load.
                job_failed(jobNumber);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                dup2(pipeOne[READ_END], 3);
                dup2(pipeThree[READ_END], 4);

                // Close pipes here.

                // Exec

                char* cmpArgs[3];
                char jobArg[14];             

                snprintf(jobArg, 14, "Job %i stdout", jobNumber);

                cmpArgs[0] = "comparison-program";
                cmpArgs[1] = jobArg;
                cmpArgs[2] = NULL;

                execvp("comparison-program", cmpArgs);

                // Job failed to load.
                job_failed(jobNumber);
            } else {
                dup2(pipeTwo[READ_END], 3);
                dup2(pipeFour[READ_END], 4);

                // Redirect to dev/null if isQuiet == 1
                int devNull = open("/dev/null", 0);

                if (isQuiet) {
                    dup2(devNull, STDOUT_FILENO);
                    dup2(devNull, STDERR_FILENO);
                } else {
                    close (devNull);
                }

                // Close pipes here.

                char* cmpArgs[3];
                char jobArg[14];             

                snprintf(jobArg, 14, "Job %i stderr", jobNumber);

                cmpArgs[0] = "comparison-program";
                cmpArgs[1] = jobArg;
                cmpArgs[2] = NULL;

                execvp("comparison-program", cmpArgs);

                // Job failed to load.
                job_failed(jobNumber);
            }
        } else {
            pidList[i] = status;
        }
    }

    ...
    // Further processing
}
```

I tried closing all non dup2 pipe ends for each child process, but this did not work and rather caused the program to timeout. Any help / guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Each program should close each file descriptor that it is not (any longer) going to use itself.  In this regard, to "use" means not only to perform I/O with the file descriptor, but also to passively hold it open until a child process that needs to inherit it has been forked. Thus, the question is not only which FDs to close, but *when*.  The failure description presented sounds like the write end of one or more of the pipes was closed too soon.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `dup2` to reserve fd 3 and 4 before creating the pipes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for the tip, yes passively holding / closing pipes in the parent process alongside the child forks was very important here as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably due to pipes being closed too early when the calls `pipe(pipeOne);`, `pipe(pipeTwo);`, `pipe(pipeThree)`, and `pipe(pipeFour);` happened to create file descriptors 3 and 4 which get reassigned by child 2 and child 3.  Child 2 and child 3 need to avoid closing file descriptors 3 and 4 too early.

For child 2, change:

```
                dup2(pipeOne[READ_END], 3);
                dup2(pipeThree[READ_END], 4);
```

to something similar to:

```
                if (pipeOne[READ_END] == 4) {
                    pipeOne[READ_END] = dup(pipeOne[READ_END]);
                    // old fd 4 will be closed by a dup2() call below
                }
                if (pipeThree[READ_END] == 3) {
                    pipeThree[READ_END] = dup(pipeThree[READ_END]);
                    // old fd 3 will be closed by a dup2() call below
                }
                dup2(pipeOne[READ_END], 3);
                dup2(pipeThree[READ_END], 4);
                // close old pipe fds except fd 3 and 4
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    int fd;
                    switch (i) {
                    case 0: fd = pipeOne[0]; break;
                    case 1: fd = pipeOne[1]; break;
                    case 2: fd = pipeTwo[0]; break;
                    case 3: fd = pipeTwo[1]; break;
                    case 4: fd = pipeThree[0]; break;
                    case 5: fd = pipeThree[1]; break;
                    case 6: fd = pipeFour[0]; break;
                    case 7: fd = pipeFour[1]; break;
                    }
                    if (fd != 3 && fd != 4) {
                        close(fd);
                    }
                }
```

For child 3, change:

```
                dup2(pipeTwo[READ_END], 3);
                dup2(pipeFour[READ_END], 4);
```

to something similar to:

```
                if (pipeTwo[READ_END] == 4) {
                    pipeTwo[READ_END] = dup(pipeTwo[READ_END]);
                    // old fd 4 will be closed by a dup2() call below
                }
                if (pipeFour[READ_END] == 3) {
                    pipeFour[READ_END] = dup(pipeFour[READ_END]);
                    // old fd 3 will be closed by a dup2() call below
                }
                dup2(pipeTwo[READ_END], 3);
                dup2(pipeFour[READ_END], 4);
                // close old pipe fds except fd 3 and 4
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    int fd;
                    switch (i) {
                    case 0: fd = pipeOne[0]; break;
                    case 1: fd = pipeOne[1]; break;
                    case 2: fd = pipeTwo[0]; break;
                    case 3: fd = pipeTwo[1]; break;
                    case 4: fd = pipeThree[0]; break;
                    case 5: fd = pipeThree[1]; break;
                    case 6: fd = pipeFour[0]; break;
                    case 7: fd = pipeFour[1]; break;
                    }
                    if (fd != 3 && fd != 4) {
                        close(fd);
                    }
                }
```

Child 0 and 1 should close both ends of `pipeOne`, `pipeTwo`, `pipeThree` and `pipeFour` after the `dup2` calls.  Assuming `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO` were already open before the calls to `pipe()`, no special checks are needed to avoid closing the pipes too early as were needed for fd 3 and 4 above.

The code could be made less verbose by replacing `pipeOne`, `pipeTwo`, `pipeThree` and `pipeFour` with a 1-D array of 8 file descriptors or a 2-D array of 4×2 file descriptors.